# Order by distinct number of rows for 3 tables?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables - `News, Content and Edits`.

Every row in each table contains a `user_id` field.

What I want to do is make a list of the top contributors to these 3 tables.

So I need to count how many times each different `user_id` appears in each table and order from the highest count to the lowest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
SELECT 
    user_id,
    COUNT(*) AS all_actions 
FROM (
    SELECT user_id FROM News
    UNION ALL
    SELECT user_id FROM Content
    UNION ALL
    SELECT user_id FROM Edits
) tmp_table
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY all_actions DESC
```

Comment: column names and table names are highly customizable ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
SELECT all_user_ids.user_id as `user_id`, COUNT(all_user_ids.user_id) as `count`
FROM
(SELECT user_id FROM news
UNION ALL
SELECT user_id FROM content
UNION ALL
SELECT user_id FROM edits) AS all_user_ids
GROUP BY `user_id`
ORDER BY `count` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a per table instance

```
SELECT DISTINCT(COUNT(user_id)) as num FROM news GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY num DESC LIMIT 0,3
```